How can I find the link of a button with hidden link?
Please observe this link (related to a sandbox report): https://cuckoo.cert.ee/analysis/5408154/export/
On this page, there is a button to download the report, but we don't have access to the direct link. In fact, if you right-click on the button, you won't see any link.
I want to write a script to download thousands of such reports, as manually downloading them is very difficult. Is there any way to find the direct link to the report?
